# Vertical Alignment of different minipages

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes, minipage

I have 3 minipages with similar layouts next to each other:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\advance\textwidth 1cm
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
        1. \underline{Abscheren des Niets}\\
    \vspace{0.1cm}
        $P_B \le P_V = Rc \dfrac{d_R^2 \pi}{4} n*m$\\
    \vspace{-0.4cm}
    \scriptsize{
    \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit}\\
        d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
        & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
        & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ geschlagener Niet}\\
        m   & =  \text{Schnittigkeit}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
    \end{align*}
    }
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
        2. \underline{\normalsize{Ausreißen durch Scherbruch}}\\
    \vspace{0.1cm}
        $P_B \le P_V = 2*e*s*R_C$\\
    \vspace{-0.4cm}
    \scriptsize{
    \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
        & \\
        & \\
    \end{align*}    
    }
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
        3. \underline{\normalsize{Ausreißen durch Spalten}}\\
    \vspace{0.1cm}
        {\tiny$P_B \le P_V = \left(e-\frac{d}{2}\right) *s *\text{min} 
                \begin{cases}
                    R_m\\
                    1,5 * R_{p0,2}\\
                \end{cases}$\\}
    \vspace{-0.4cm}
    \scriptsize{
    \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        R_M & =  \text{Bruchfestigkeit (Zug)}\\
        R_{p0,2} & = \text{Dehngrenze}\\
    \end{align*}
    }
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

There are 2 issues:

1) The third title isn't in line with the other two titles (I have no idea why).

2) The equations and text blocks aren't aligned.

Is there a way to align different boxes over several minipages or do I have to create 3 minipages for every triplet of align blocks that I want?

Thanks!

Comment: font size commands like `\scriptsize`, `\tiny` etc do not take an argument

Comment: Really? I always thought that that would only give the enclosed text the specified font size.

Comment: `\scriptsize{...}` is not the same as `{\scriptsize ...}`

Comment: no `\small{foo}` will make all the  text in the document small (unless in a group)

Comment: I fixed your example so people can use it to see the issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\noindent` immediately ahead of the first `minipage`.

Don't use `\underline`. Instead, load the `ulem` package and use `\uline{...}`.

Don't use `*` to indicate multiplication. Either omit the symbol entirely (it won't be missed...) or use `\cdot`.

And, don't use `\tiny` for the equation in the third `minipage` unless you want to convey a sense that you hate your readers. I would rewrite the equation so that it runs over two lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,babel,siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    1. \uline{Abscheren des Niets}

    \vspace{0.1cm}
    $P_B \le P_V = Rc \tfrac{1}{4}d_R^2 \pi nm$\\
    \vspace{-0.4cm}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit}\\
        d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & =  d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & =  d + \SI{0,05}{\milli\metre} 
                 \text{ geschlagener Niet}\\
        m   & =  \text{Schnittigkeit}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    2. \uline{Ausreißen durch Scherbruch}

    \vspace{0.1cm}
    $P_B \le P_V = 2esR_C$

    \vspace{-0.4cm}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}
    \end{align*}    
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    3. \uline{Ausreißen durch Spalten}

    \vspace{-0.6cm}
    \small
    \begin{multline*}
    P_B \le P_V = (e-\tfrac{1}{2}d) s \\
        \times\min(R_m,\num{1,5}  R_{p\num{0,2}})
    \end{multline*}

    \vspace{-0.6cm}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        R_M & =  \text{Bruchfestigkeit (Zug)}\\
        R_{p0,2} & = \text{Dehngrenze}\\
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips, it looks just like I want it now!

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough width to keep your headings on one line to maintain alignment, I just made the page wider here but you may prefer to change the text.

Also I deleted the spurious braces after size change commands and removed the `\\` which should hardly ever be used outside tables, and never at the end of a paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\advance\textwidth 2cm
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
        1.~\underline{Abscheren des Niets}

        $P_B \le P_V = Rc \dfrac{d_R^2 \pi}{4} n*m$

    \scriptsize
    \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit}\\
        d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
        & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
        & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ geschlagener Niet}\\
        m   & =  \text{Schnittigkeit}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
        2.~\underline{\normalsize{Ausreißen durch Scherbruch}}

        $P_B \le P_V = 2*e*s*R_C$

    \scriptsize
    \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
        & \\
        & \\
    \end{align*}     
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
        3.~\underline{\normalsize{Ausreißen durch Spalten}}

    \vspace{0.1cm}
        \tiny$P_B \le P_V = \left(e-\frac{d}{2}\right) *s *\text{min} 
                \begin{cases}
                    R_m\\
                    1,5 * R_{p0,2}\\
                \end{cases}$

    \scriptsize
    \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        R_M & =  \text{Bruchfestigkeit (Zug)}\\
        R_{p0,2} & = \text{Dehngrenze}\\
    \end{align*}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't fixing anything though, it still looks the same as before, even with the fixed code..

Comment: @Skydiver your question wasn't very clear but I thought the main issue was that the titles were not aligned, and this fixes that which means that the equations under the titles also align....

Comment: Look at Mico's post to see what I meant.

Comment: @Skydiver Sorry I don't see the difference in alignment (Mico went further and corrected some other poor markup but still just aligns the titles, as I did)  Herbert's answer aligns the titles, the display math and the align separately, so from your initial comment I assumed you meant that. However no matter you have plenty of answers now to solve the problem:-)

Comment: I sorry that I misformulated my question, I should have more explicitly stated what the issue was. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @Skydiver no harm done:-)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\noindent\footnotesize
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
  1.~\underline{Abscheren des Niets}
\[P_B \le P_V = Rc \dfrac{d_R^2 \pi}{4} n*m\]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
2.~\underline{Ausreißen durch Scherbruch}
\[P_B \le P_V = 2*e*s*R_C\vphantom{\frac{d^2_R}{4}}\]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
\centering
3.~\underline{Ausreißen durch Spalten}

\tiny
\[P_B \le P_V = \left(e-\frac{d}{2}\right) *s *\text{min} 
        \begin{cases}
        R_m\\
        1,5 * R_{p0,2}\\
        \end{cases}\]
\end{minipage}

\noindent
\scriptsize
%\fontsize{6pt}{6.1pt}\selectfont
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit}\\
        d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
        & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
        & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ geschlagener Niet}\\
        m   & =  \text{Schnittigkeit}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
        \end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
        & \\
        & \\
        \end{align*}     
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        R_M & =  \text{Bruchfestigkeit (Zug)}\\
        R_{p0,2} & = \text{Dehngrenze}\\
        \end{align*}        
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]